# Would you start a customer's project using JavaFX 2+ for desktop GUI?

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2

I'm interested in your opionion concerning JavaFX 2+ and it's role in the future concerning the creation of desktop applications.

Imagine to start a new customer's project that requires a desktop GUI component.

- Would you recommend using JavaFX for a GUI component?
- Do you still prefer to use swing?
- What are the pros and cons?
- Are there known barriers?
- If you even started a customer's project using JavaFX, would you do it again?

Personally, I believe in JavaFX and the ability to create GUIs for a great user experience.

I'm looking forward for a good and interesting exchange of opionions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently asking myself the same thing. Some months ago. I have built a small specialised dictionary application using Swing, JPA 2.0 (eclipselink) and SQLite. 
I just started to port this to JavaFX2. I am very curious how it will turn out, and it might answer some of the same questions you ask (though still in a specific context of course).

If you like, I can keep you updated about the progress.

Comment: Yes, please :) I would appreciate sharing your experience with us in the context of this question.

Comment: ok, will do. I'm already having my first issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467015/jpa-createentitymanagerfactory-unknown-source-error-non-j2ee